Spring boot application with MYSQL
I have done poc with spring boot application with mysql db, so far i have used docker compose file to bring the spring boot and mysql container in my windows system and i can able to access sample application from the browser using localhost with default port 8080.
docker-compose.yaml
version: "3"
services: 
  springboot-app:
   # container_name: spring-app
    image: springbooot-app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysqldb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
  mysqldb: 
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./springboot-docker-compose/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports: 
     - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        

application.porperties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

Here the docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                               NAMES
686737f46e0e   mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   mysqldb
56ecbcb915ac   springbooot-app                                                              "java -jar app.jar"      16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp              springbook-mysql-springboot-app-1

Here the sprint boot logs
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:24.289  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:24.348  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:24.348  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:24.612  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:24.612  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5840 ms
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:25.372  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:25.566  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.3.Final
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:26.542  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:27.016  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:28.571  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:28.794  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:31.864  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:31.899  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:32.070  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:33.161  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:05:33.211  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.d.SpringBootDockerComposeApplication : Started SpringBootDockerComposeApplication in 16.474 seconds (JVM running for 18.649)
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:06:07.881  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:06:07.881  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
springboot-app-1  | 2024-04-08 13:06:07.886  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms

I'm new to the devops side, now the plan is i want to move the docker-compose yaml into a single dockerfile to create docker image with combination if mysql + spring boot application in single file so that i will deploy the image into EKS cluster POC environment not in production ready environment.

what exactly effect  you want ?
move the docker-compose yaml into a single dockerfile to create docker image with combination if mysql + spring boot application in single file
you mean compose mysql and application in single dockerfile ?

Thanks for response. Yes I need single dockerfile to manage all the above activities.

build a ubuntu image and get them all you need embed  in it .

but database is  independent service ,  i mean that  it may  service for other application in future , beside your current application in single dockerfile ,  not sure what scenario would take the solution like this ?

Hi All @ thanks for your support.
i have create two different images one for spring boot app and another one for mysql DB. Post that i have update the application.properites file to point my namesapce.svc.cluster.local, post this changes i can able to start my application pod and able to retrive the table from mysql pod.
